# Got this error "Comma, ')', or a valid expression continuation expected"

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

can anyone  help me to solve this error. Got error at line

```
wtp.Add(New WaterTreament() With {.position = positionName, .value = Convert.ToDouble(sqlRs2("value").ToString()), .timestamp = sqlRs2("dtimestamp").ToString()})
```

Here's  the code

```
    Dim wtp As New List(Of WaterTreament)()
    sqlRs2.Open(strSQL2, objConn2)
       If Not sqlRs2.EOF Then
        Dim positionName = sqlRs2("position").ToString()
        If (positionName = "60") Then
            positionName = "CHLORINE"
        ElseIf (positionName = "61") Then
            positionName = "TURBIDITY"
        ElseIf (positionName = "62") Then
            positionName = "PH"
        ElseIf (positionName = "63") Then
            positionName = "FLORIDE"
        End If
        wtp.Add(New WaterTreament() With {.position = positionName, .value = Convert.ToDouble(sqlRs2("value").ToString()), .timestamp = sqlRs2("dtimestamp").ToString()})
    End If
```

Comment: what is SqlRs2? By the way, It is good practice that you define an object before you use it.

Comment: Actually SqlRs2 is a  "sqlRs2 = New ADODB.Recordset()"

Comment: Is it using `Option Strict On`? That can make Visual Studio better at pointing to problems.

Comment: Why ADODB? This has been replaced by ADO.net a long time ago.

Comment: You could write a custom constructor for WaterTreatment class. This would simplify the code a bit and you would have intellisense to help you.

Comment: I think you just have an extra ) close parenthesis on that line.

Answer (score 0):

Well, sometimes it is REALLY a lot better to just write out a few extra lines of code. I mean, fancy pants can be cool, and great, but often a few extra lines of code is a bettter approach.

So, say try this:

```
dim MyWaterTreat as new WaterTrament

MyWaterTreat.position = positionName
MyWaterTreat.value = Convert.ToDouble(sqlRs2("Value).ToString())
MyWaterTreat.TimeStamp = sqlRs2("dtimesamp").ToString()

wtp.Add(MyWaterTreat)
```

You get much nicer intel-sense, and probably save a pot of coffee in the debugging process anyway.

So, sometimes, you better off to write a few extra lines of code. And with VS, then say ctr-d to duplicate the previous line? You might result in a bit more code but you the developer did not actually have to type in that code, or all that much of it.

So, create a new instance of the class. Add the values along with GREAT nice intel-sense, and then add that new object to the list.

Better yet, you also tend to get intel-sense for miss matched data types.